# Kafka Connect "worker_id" set to loopback "127.0.1.1:8083"?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have a three node Confluent Kafka cluster. Each node is runing zookeeper, kafka broker, schema-registry, and kafka connect.

I have configured an S3 sink. It seems to be functioning, but the `worker_id` is set to a loopback ip address rather than a unique IP, which looks wrong:

```
curl "localhost:8083/connectors/my-s3-sink/status" | jq '.'

{
  "name": "my-s3-sink",
  "connector": {
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "worker_id": "127.0.1.1:8083"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "state": "RUNNING",
      "id": 0,
      "worker_id": "127.0.1.1:8083"
    }
  ],
  "type": "sink"
}
```

How is Kafka Connect getting the `127.0.1.1:8083` loopback address? I presume this is not correct for a production three node cluster.

How can I check my cluster configuration to find the problem?

I launch Kafka Connect through systemd via `/usr/bin/connect-distributed /etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties` and `bootstrap.servers` in that properties file is set to the three node IPs that do not resolve to the loopback IP. (I `x` out actual IP values for privacy)

```
bootstrap.servers=172.x.x.x:9092,172.x.x.x:9092,172.x.x.x:9092
```

My Kafka Brokers are configured with `/etc/kafka/server.properties` settings:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
# EC2 public hostname
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://ec2-34-x-x-x.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9092
# EC2 internal/private hostnames. localhost entry will resolve to 127.0.1.1
zookeeper.connect=ip-172-x-x-x.us-west-2.compute.internal:2181,ip-172-x-x-x.us-west-2.compute.internal:2181,ip-172-x-x-x.us-west-2.compute.internal:2181
```

And `/etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties` is configured with:

```
server.1=172.x.x.x:2888:3888
server.2=172.x.x.x:2888:3888
server.3=172.x.x.x:2888:3888
```

Comment: Look at `/etc/hosts`, but you really should not run all those services on each machine.

Comment: Is there a reason why I shouldn't run all four kafka services on each kafka node? Is there a best practices guide that you would recommend?

Comment: Somewhere in the connector documentation, it says not to rub on the brokers. The zookeeper prefer SSDs, but the Kafka brokers, connect servers, and schema registry do not. If you plan on scaling out, you really only need a maximum of three registries, and having more than three or five Zookeepers is not recommended, and only 5 is needed for large Kafka deployments... My point is that Kafka should have large, dedicated disks with lots of memory allocated to the heap. Zookeeper stores all state in memory, and should be quick to respond.A Connect cluster should be able to scale separately

Comment: At an absolute minimum, though, the Kafka and Zookeeper data & log directories are mounted on different physical disks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `rest.host.name` needs to be configure to be the IP or hostname of each instance in `connect-distributed.properties`. The cluster leader uses the rest api to balance tasks across the cluster so also update `rest.host.port` if you are not using 8083.

```
# Hostname & Port for the REST API to listen on. If this is set, 
# it will bind to the interface used to listen to requests.
#rest.host.name=
#rest.port=8083
```

Comment: fyi, I wanted to change `rest.advertised.host.name`. `rest.host.name` is the listen address which is fine as default.